# Silverlight: How to load files in directory included in XAP folder

Tags: c#, silverlight, file-io, silverlight-5.0

I have a folder with a list of files that I've included in my silverlight solution as "Content".  I know how to load individual files using Application.GetResourceStream(), but I wish to load an entire directory with multiple files in it.

Attempted to use DirectoryInfo but it throws a Securityexception, and using Application.GetResourceStream() with a directory path returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using a standard file naming convention, with a specified index in the filename, and then I just build each filename with using a loop and the index of the loop and load each stream into an array.